# Need to align and style MUI icon button & text input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have designed a modal dialog that uses increment & decrement buttons on text-input values.
I need to align and put some style to it. as per the image it's not really looking good.
anyway, it does the functions.

[image: screenshot]
I want something like this for adult tickets I don't need +/- buttons
[image: screenshot 1]
Code

```
    <ul>
     <li> 
       Adult Tickets &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <TextField
            value={AdSeatCount}
            id="outlined-adornment-small-Adult"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 48, height: 35}}
            labelWidth={0}
            disabled="true"
            />
            <br/>
            </li>
            <li>Child Tickets
<div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>                                 
              <IconButton
               onClick={this.onMinusClick}
               aria-label="minus"
               style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
              >
              <RemoveCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                </IconButton>
                 <TextField
                  value={this.state.value}
                  id="outlined-adornment-small-Child"
                  variant="outlined"
                  size="small"
                   style={{ width: 48, height: 35 ,marginTop: 15}}
                   labelWidth={0}
                   disabled="true"
                   />
                   <IconButton
                    onClick={this.onPlusClick}
                     aria-label="plus"
                     style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                     >
                     <AddCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                    </IconButton>
</div>
               </li>
           </ul>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQQYf.png
```

Comment: Make a flex box and center row contents

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the Stack component that gives you out of the box all the attributes you need to have the desired result.

In this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-demo-material-ui-forked-cklqzd?file=/demo.tsx) is your solution, (I had to replace some of the state stuff for the values.) Please note that I also had to remove some of the css you has added as it was wrong.

Here is you refactored code, note that you had to import the `Stack` component

```
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";

<ul>
    <li>
      <Stack
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="flex-start"
      alignItems="center"
      spacing={1}
      my={2}
    >
      Adult Tickets &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <TextField
        value={AdSeatCount}
        id="outlined-adornment-small-Adult"
        variant="outlined"
        size="small"
        style={{ width: 48 }}
        labelWidth={0}
        disabled="true"
      />
    </Stack>
  </li>
  <li>
  <Stack
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="flex-start"
      alignItems="center"
      spacing={1}
      my={2}
    >
    Child Tickets
    
      <IconButton
        onClick={this.onMinusClick}
        aria-label="minus"
        
      >
        <RemoveCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
      </IconButton>
      <TextField
        value={this.state.value}
        id="outlined-adornment-small-Child"
        variant="outlined"
        size="small"
        style={{ width: 48}}
        labelWidth={0}
        disabled="true"
      />
      <IconButton
        onClick={this.onPlusClick}
        aria-label="plus"
        
      >
        <AddCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
      </IconButton>
    </Stack>
    
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the `IconButtons` and the `TextField` in a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) div, as follows.

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
  <IconButton
    onClick={this.onMinusClick}
    aria-label="minus"
    style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
  >
    <RemoveCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
  </IconButton>
  <TextField
    value={this.state.value}
    id="outlined-adornment-small-Child"
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    style={{ width: 48, height: 35, marginTop: 15 }}
    labelWidth={0}
    disabled="true"
  />
  <IconButton
    onClick={this.onPlusClick}
    aria-label="plus"
    style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
  >
    <AddCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
  </IconButton>
</div>
```

To align horizontally, here's some pseudocode to keep things clean.

```
<div style={{ display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "auto 1fr", gridTemplateRows: "auto auto" }}>
  <AdultLabel style={{ gridColumn: "1 / 2", gridRow: "1 / 2" }} />
  <AdultInput style={{ gridColumn: "2 / 3", gridRow: "1 / 2" }} />
  <ChildLabel style={{ gridColumn: "1 / 2", gridRow: "2 / 3" }} />
  <ChildInput style={{ gridColumn: "2 / 3", gridRow: "2 / 3" }} />
</div>
```

Of course you would keep everything cleaner if you used a CSS file as follows:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.label {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.labelAdult {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.labelChild {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.label {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: after done your changes, i have updated the question. still not aligned

Comment: Are you trying to align the two input fields horizontally?

Comment: yes along with the icon buttons

Comment: To get perfect alignment, you probably want to create a CSS Grid setup with labels on the left and inputs on the right.

Comment: can you provide a suggestion as an answer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for... perhaps if you were able to draw it out or provide a mockup of the layout you're trying to achieve I can write some code for you.

Comment: I've updated the response with all the info I can give.  Best of luck on your project!